# change a column that contain date and time with two columns containing date and time separately

Tags: python, pandas

I have some columns in a dataset that contain date and time and my goal is to obtain two separate columns that contain date and time separately.

Example:

Name Dataset: A

Starting

Name column: Cat

```
         12/01/2021  20:15:06
         02/01/2021  12:15:07                  
         01/01/2021  15:05:03                   
         01/01/2021  15:05:03
```

Goal

Name column:   Cat1

```
           12/01/2021       
           02/01/2021       
           01/01/2021       
           01/01/2021
```

Name Column:   Cat2

```
           20:15:06
           12:15:07 
           15:05:03
           15:05:03
```

Comment: You mean two separate dataframes? Are you using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you 're using pandas, and that you want to use the same dataframe.

```
# df = A (?)

df['Cat1'] = [d.date() for d in df['Cat']]
df['Cat2'] = [d.time() for d in df['Cat']]
```

Working example:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
{'A': [1, 2, 3],
 'B': [4, 5, 6],
 'Datetime': [datetime.strftime(datetime.now()-timedelta(days=_),
                                "%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S") for _ in range(3)]},
orient='index',
columns=['A', 'B', 'C']).T

df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], format="%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

#    A  B            Datetime
# A  1  4 2021-03-05 14:07:59
# B  2  5 2021-03-04 14:07:59
# C  3  6 2021-03-03 14:07:59

df['Cat1'] = [d.date() for d in df['Datetime']]
df['Cat2'] = [d.time() for d in df['Datetime']]
#    A  B            Datetime        Cat1      Cat2
# A  1  4 2021-03-05 14:07:59  2021-03-05  14:07:59
# B  2  5 2021-03-04 14:07:59  2021-03-04  14:07:59
# C  3  6 2021-03-03 14:07:59  2021-03-03  14:07:59
```

Comment: yes I am using pandas, i want the same dataframe but with two different columns. The starting dataframe has one single column with date and time.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. I think that it solves your question.

Comment: I have the value error: "NaTType does not support time"

Comment: Good question, maybe not, how can I check? or obtain datetime format? However for the date it works! the problem is only for time

Comment: I added a working example, see if it helps you.